# Can 7 Hoffman-Singleton graphs cover $K_{50}$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, open-problem

Three copies of the [Clebsch Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClebschGraph.html) can cover $K_{16}$, the complete graph on 16 vertices. This is part of the demonstration that $\mathrm{Ramsey}(3,3,3) > 16$.

[image: Clebsch 3-cover of K_16]

The [Hoffman–Singleton graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoffman%E2%80%93Singleton_graph) is a (7,5)-cage, and is one of the more famous graphs in graph theory. Can 7 copies of this graph cover the complete graph $K_{50}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a curious question, but it seems to be an open problem.  I found a discussion of it here:

Jana Ŝiagiová, Mariusz Meszka, *[A covering construction for packing disjoint copies of the Hoffman-Singleton graph into K<sub>50</sub>](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jcd.10049)*, J. Combin. Des. 11 (2003), no. 6, 408–412.

> A complete solution seems to be difﬁcult to obtain; nevertheless we show a
>   construction of packing of ﬁve Hoffman-Singleton graphs into K<sub>50</sub> using the covering method.

and elsewhere in the paper

> The question whether more than ﬁve copies of the Hoffman-Singleton graph can
>   be packed into K<sub>50</sub> still remains open.